# How do I query for subclasses in embedded documents with mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Box, with many toys of various types:

```
class Box
    embeds_many :toys
end

class Toy
   field :name
   embedded_in :box
end

class Car < Toy
end

class Doll < Toy
end
```

If I have found the specific box object I want, how do I query it to find just the cars?

```
my_box.toys.where(??? Car ??? )
```

Obviously I could iterate over each toy and extract the ones where `toy.is_a? Car`, but I'm looking for a solution, if one exists, that just uses the built in mongoid criteria/finders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a good question. luckily Mongoid used to store `_type` meta attribute in the document to handle these kind of scenarios

so you can find the cars in the box by

```
  Box.where('toys._type'=>'Car')
```

Thats all

Comment: Just for completeness: if you already had the box object it would be `box.toys.where(_type: 'Car')`  Thanks for the help.